Why did I get two different values for $\zeta(0,a)$?
The first method: Using the definition of Hurwitz Zeta Function, we have:
$$\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ 1}{(n+a)^s}$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ 1}{n^s}-\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}\frac{ 1}{n^s}$$
$$= \zeta(s)-\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}\frac{ 1}{n^s}$$
$$\zeta( 0,a)=\zeta(0)-\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}1$$
$$=\frac{-1}{2}-(a-1)=\frac{ 1}{2}-a$$
This is true for all positive integer $a$.
The second method: By this Wikipedia page, the Lerch Transcendent $\Phi(x, s, a):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ x^n}{(n+a)^s}$ is the generalisation of $\zeta(s,a)$, where $\Phi(1,s,a)=\zeta(s,a)$
Therefore, if we know what $\Phi(x,0,a)$ is, we should also know what $\zeta( 0,a)$ is.
$$\Phi(x, s, a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ x^n}{(n+a)^s}$$
$$\Phi(x, 0, a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
By analytic continuation, if $x\rightarrow 1$, $\Phi(x,s,a)\rightarrow\zeta(s,a)$. However, $\underset{x\rightarrow 1^+}{\lim} \Phi(x, 0, a)=\infty$. Why is the two values different? Furthermore, if we define $\Phi(1,s,a)=\zeta(s,a)$, aren't we making it discontinuous at $s=0$?

You're trying to extend the Lerch Transcendent beyond its range of convergence.

That’s exactly what I was thinking about. I need to take $(x,s)\rightarrow(1,0)$, and it turns out that the order does matter. That means Lerch Transcendent is not continuous in the plane $(x,s)=(1,0)$. I was asking whether this idea was correct.
